# Pipe each last run command to a script

Tags: bash

I want to use [realiser](https://github.com/paulmars/realiaser) to know if I should have used an alias each time I run a command in my bash terminal.

The README gives the following example for ZSH:

```
function last_command() {
  echo `history -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 3-20 | realiaser`
}

RPROMPT='%{$fg[$NCOLOR]%}%p $(last_command)%{$reset_color%}'
```

It says "Check the options on your machine for "history". This configuration is for ZSH and needs slight ajusting for Bash or other configuartions" but I can't find how to adapt it for my bash, I currently have the following but don't know how to adapt it:

```
function parse_git_branch {
  git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
function prompt {
PS1="${TITLEBAR}\
\w\$(parse_git_branch)\
 \$ "
}
prompt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the function prompt, for setting up PS1. Just export PS1 in your profile. You can use the same last_command function from the ZSH example and stick it in your PS1.

```
export PS1='${TITLEBAR}\w $(parsebranch) $(last_command) \$'
```